# enable button after filling out

Tags: java, swing

I have a button I want disabled until several comboboxes and textfields have been filled out correctly in Java Swing. I thought of having a validation function, but I'm not sure how would that work nor how would I call it every time something is changed.

Comment: Exactly,you need to have a validation function which will check for each combo-box and other components and then enable the `JButton`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the button default to off. Place an if statement above the actionListener. Set the if statement to false. Now the button cannot be pressed until true. Whenever one of the required fields is clicked/has information entered into it, check its actionListener to see if the information entered is acceptable. If so, then check to see if all other required fields have acceptable values. If they do, then turn the button on and set its actionListener to true.

To keep track of acceptable fields, create a boolean array with X values where X = the amount of required fields. If that field contains an acceptable value, then set that array position to true.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can try to get all change-events of all comboboxes, textfields and stuff and everytime, one of those events is fired, you run your validation function, that checks all content!

If this is too much work or too complicated for you, you can also start a thread, that checks your inputs every half second or so and enables the button, when everything is ok. But I would not reconment this solution, because, it is not that nice and genteel!

Answer (score 0):

To get notified when a JTextField changes use a DocumentListener: `someTextField.getDocument().addDocumentListener( ... );` for a JComboBox use an ActionListener: `someComboBox.addActionListener (new ActionListener () { ... });`

Every time one of these is called check all values and decide whether to enable the button or not.